# For all $n>2$: there exists $p$ prime: $n<p<n!$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, prime-numbers, solution-verification

The question is:

**For all $n>2$, where $n \in \mathbb Z$: there exists $p$ prime such that $n<p<n!$**

Here is my Proof:

$\forall$ $p<n: p|n!$, or $p$ divides $n!$

Since $n!$ and $n!-1$ are relatively prime

$=>$ $n!$ and $n!-1$ share no common divisors

$=>$ there must a prime $p > n$ such that $p | (n!-1)$

I feel like it needs to be clarified more. What else should I add?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: the idea is correct, you can explain why $p|n!$ for $p\leq n$ for better clarity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To me, it looks correct, and I wouldn't add much more. You may want to add that $n!-1 > 2$, just in case.

Of course, the level of precision needed in an argument depends on who you are talking to and in what circumstances: a research paper would surely take things such as this problem for granted, while in a homework assignment this level of precision should be appropriate.

A much stronger statement is true. It is called [Bertrard's postulate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_postulate), and says that for any $n \geq 2$ you can find a prime $p$ such that $n < p < 2n$.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible  proof:

Let $S=\{ x \in \mathbf{Z^+} : n<x<n! \text{ and for every prime divisor } d \text{ of } x ,d \leq n \}$ . Since $(n!-1) \in S$ , the well-ordering principle implies that exists a minimal element in $S$ , called $n_0$ . This $n_0$ is prime.